How to use R/Python effectively in high performance computer?
I am starting to using supercomputer for my sequencing analysis. So far, it is not progressing well at all because I normally use R and Python via my Windows computer.
My question is that how could it use it effectively and fast because I just got base R via supercomputer and it is just slow (attached images) and not sure how to save my codes.
Is there any IDE that can link to supercomputer to conveniently use R or Python?


Thanks for your responses. In supercomputer. I used command module load R/4.4.1 and thenR. it just gave me based R, which is hard to use compared with R studio in my local computer. What is your experience of running R or python in supercomputer? do you have any best way to use? Kind Regards
